# Find element with attribute with minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Given

```
<field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000008000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000008000"/>
<field name="frame.time_relative" showname="Time since reference or first frame: 0.000008000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000008000"/>
<field name="frame.number" showname="Frame Number: 2" size="0" pos="0" show="2"/>
<field name="frame.pkt_len" showname="Packet Length: 1506 bytes" hide="yes" size="0" pos="0" show="1506"/>
<field name="frame.len" showname="Frame Length: 1506 bytes" size="0" pos="0" show="1506"/>
<field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 1506 bytes" size="0" pos="0" show="1506"/>
<field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
<field name="frame.protocols" showname="Protocols in frame: eth:ip:tcp:http:data" size="0" pos="0" show="eth:ip:tcp:http:data"/>
```

How do I get the field with name="frame.len" right away without iterating through every tag and checking the attributes?

Comment: To add to this question, the xml is 300mb. I ran out of memory last time I tried to parse it. Any suggestions of better sax style libraries?

Comment: Well, `xml.dom.minidom` is a DOM parser that needs to read the entire document into memory. Not because it's not good enough but because that's what DOM parsers do. So I don't know what you mean by "better sax style libraries". What's bad about `xml.sax`, the standard SAX parser that comes with Python?

Comment: After 5000 packets (300mb), trying to load the xml crashes my computer. Out of that 300mb of data, I just need about 10kb that's spread out across the document. Is there a more efficient way of traversing the xml than lxml and a more simple library than sax?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can.

From the parent `element`, you need to

```
for subelement in element.GetElementsByTagName("field"):
    if subelement.hasAttribute("frame.len"):
        do_something()
```

Reacting to your comment from March 11, if the structure of your documents is stable and free of nasty surprises (like angle brackets inside attributes), you might want to try the unthinkable and use a regular expression. This is not recommended practice but could work and be much easier than actually parsing the file. I admit that I've done that sometimes myself. Haven't gone blind yet.

So in your case you could (assuming that a `<field>` tag doesn't span multiple lines):

```
xmlfile = open("myfile.xml")
for line in xmlfile:
    match = re.search(r'<field\s+name="frame.len"\s+([^>]+)/>', line):
    if match:
        result = match.group(1)
        do_something(result)
```

If a `<field>` tag *can* span multiple lines, you could try loading the entire file as plain text into memory and then scan it for matches:

```
filedump = open("myfile.xml").read()
for match in re.finditer(r'<field\s+name="frame.len"\s+([^>]+)/>', filedump):
    result = match.group(1)
    do_something(result)
```

In both cases, `result` will contain the attributes other than `frame.len`. The regex assumes that `frame.len` is always the first attribute inside the tag.

Answer (score 2):

You don't -- the [DOM API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html), somewhat poorly designed (by w3c, not by Python!-) doesn't have such a search function to do the iteration for you. Either accept the need to loop (not through **every** tag in general, but through all with a given tag name), or upgrade to a richer interface, such as `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that regex is horrible! As of 2016, there is a `.getAttribute()` method for each `DOMElement` that makes things a bit easier, but you still have to iterate through the elements.

```
l = []
for e in elements:
    if e.hasAttribute('name') and e.getAttribute('name') == 'field.len':
        l.append(e)
```