# Python minidom check element exists

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have a xml file with this structure:

```
<?DOMParser ?> 
<logbook:LogBook xmlns:logbook="http://www/logbook/1.0"  version="1.2">
<visits>
<visit>
    <general>
       <technology>EB</technology>
    </general>
</visit>
<visit>
<general>
    <grade>23242</grade>
    <technology>EB</technology>
</general>
</visit>
</visits>
</logbook:LogBook>
```

I want to check if each column exists in the `visit` tag, and if it does not exist I want to return None, so i wrote this code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
mydict={}
columnsLst=['grade','technology']
doc=minidom.parse('file.xml')
visitcount=len(doc.getElementsByTagName('visit'))
for i in range(visitcount):
   for c in columnsLst:
      if(doc.getElementsByTagName(c)[i].firstChild):
         mydict[c]=doc.getElementsByTagName(c)[i].firstChild.data
   print(mydict)
```

This does not work, since it does not return None for elements that does not exist. and I get `index error` since `grade` does not exist for first `visit`.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415115/find-element-with-attribute-with-minidom) as well  to use hasChild() but it gives error:

> ```
>  'Element' object has no attribute 'hasChild'
> ```

Any idea here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: minidom check element exists

Instead of fideling with Indices use the Resulting NodeLists, for example:

```
# Get List of Nodes with Tag <visit>
visits = doc.getElementsByTagName('visit')

# Iterate NodeList
for n, visit in enumerate(visits, 1):
    print('{}:{}'.format(n, visit))

    # Get SubNodes with Tag <general>
    general = visit.getElementsByTagName('general')

    # First Error Condition
    if general:
        # Iterate all Tag Names
        for subtag in ['grade', 'technology']:
            # Second Error Condition, assuming only ONE SubNode <general>
            if not general[0].getElementsByTagName(subtag):
                print('\tMissing Subtag <{}>'.format(subtag))
    else:
        print('\tMissing Tag <general>')
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> <Element {http://www/logbook/1.0}LogBook at 0xf707f52c>
> 1:<DOM Element: visit at 0xf6a6125c>
>     Missing Subtag <grade>
> 2:<DOM Element: visit at 0xf6a6184c>
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I met the same problem, it looks like there is no method to check whether the element is there or not.

You can get the element by name first using  `getElementsByTagName()` and then check the length of the NodeList. For example:

```
    for xml_txt in test:
        DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_txt)
        b = DOMTree.getElementsByTagName('Track')
        if len(b) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            b = b[0]
```